# Programmatically retrieving the path to memory-placed tmpfs

Tags: linux, ipc, tmpfs

I'm writing an application for Linux-based systems that makes intense use of temporary files for IPC purposes (locks, pipes, ...) and I would like to know if there is any canonical way to get a path to the temporary file system **residing in RAM memory** (such as /run). So far my solution is to default to `/run` unless a particular environment variable is set containing the path to that location, but I wonder whether there exists any API that could be used for getting such information. Otherwise, what is your most common approach?

Thank you.

Comment: Off the top of my head a kludge could be using `shm_open` to obtain a file desciptor, then obtain the path using `fcntl(fd, F_GETPATH, filePath);`. Interesting question, +1 :)

Comment: And interesting answer, @Geoffrey!

Comment: @Geoffrey posix shared memory files are located in /dev/shm

Comment: @kjohri correct, which is a tmpfs, I did state it was a kludge :)